# Excel show sheet inside scrollable square

Tags: vba, excel

A client is asking me what I think should be done with .NET Windows Forms or similar, but maybe it's possible to do in Excel:

I already added some buttons and actions in a data sheet, but instead of showing all cells as shown by default by Excel, he wants the sheet to be inside an scrollable area. Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible? In case it's not clear enough, the scrollbars are just around the data rows and columns, not about the buttons and form items around the actual data

**EIDT:** I'll try to be more clear, I need all my Excel sheet and workspace to look like a Windows forms application, and the actual data (all the Excel cells) to be inside an scrollable area. I think it's not easy to understand because it's quite weird, as I sayed is my client who wants this.

*BTW it wasn't a trial version, I payed for the wireframe software*

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/07/24/show-only-few-rows-columns-in-excel/? If not, then I probably misunderstood and you might want to refine your question a bit.

Comment: No, it's not that, I added some more text

Comment: Then your only option is to use a form and when opening the Excel file only the form will be shown and Excel will be hidden as demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nlJuW0yK6U The only problem with such forms is that they are static in size. You won't be able to "maximize" the window / form. But other than that it can look just the way you want it to be (design it to be). Alternatively, you might want to look into using MS-Access. It might be a bit easier to accomplish what you want to do there.

Comment: Maybe the Microsoft Office Spreadsheet control available on your VBA forms toolbox?  You can then add the sheet directly on the form - although I admit I've never used it, so no idea of what functionality it includes.

Comment: In response to @Ralphs last comment - you could maximize the form when it opens by using the code I found here:  http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/userform-controls-autofit-to-screen-size.16703/

Answer (score 0):

You could put the buttons in the top row(s) and use the Freeze Pane option

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-3439cfe6-010c-4d2d-a3c9-d0e8ba62d724?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US